# Working with a sql database on SQL Server 2012 and work with the same database on SQL Server Express 2012 is the same?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I have this question about the SQL Server and SQL Server Express. 
In my client machine, the database that he's using is SQL Server 2012 and in my machine i have SQL Server 2005.. so i want to install another instance and a friend told me that i dont need to install the SQL Server 2012 Standard (the one that they have) and with the SQL Server 2012 Express will work.. is that ok?

I really don't know the real difference in working with SQL Server Express 2012 and SQL Server Standard 2012 (with the same database).

Comment: That depends, Express has a bunch of limitations, the most likely to affect you are features that aren't available there, and database size (10 GB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On of the major differences is that with express you not be able to back ups over the network.  Local backups only.  When I do back ups from the SqlExpress Server Manager Studio it doesn't recognize mounted drives.  Check out this for a more formal approach to your question

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx][1]

Comment: The way I got around moving data via C# was to execute SqlBackup script remotely, look for the file on the network and then transfer over over the network and then do a remote sqlRestore

Answer (score 0):

Check through this document:

[Features supported by the editions of SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

You will soon be able to see if there are any features that you are using in standard that are not available in express.

Comment: But at level of attaching a database or importing it from a backup (made in SQL Server 2012) to Express do i will be having some problem with that? some version change or something?

Comment: Nope, that will work fine so long as the database doesn't use any features only present in standard edition or is larger than 10gb, if this is the case it will attach or restore, but not start up.